# Call an overriden function from an Abstract class

Tags: magento-1.9, module, model

I'm creating a new module for allowing me to work with currency exchanges.
For doing this I'm extending this class:

```
Mage_Directory_Model_Currency_Import_Abstract
```

Overriding this method:

```
abstract protected function _convert($currencyFrom, $currencyTo);
```

Now that my module is installed, I don't know how I can call this method from my checkout classes. I want to convert some prices.

I could call it using:

```
Mage::getModel('my_currencyconverter/my_model')->_convert('USD', 'EUR');
```

But I had to change first that previous function visibility, from protected to public.

How do I use this new function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use the method outside the object it must be a public function not a protected as started in the abstract class.

But when you are extending a class with abstract methods it means you have to define them yourself them yourself.

If you have decleared it however, define a public function that can call the code

```
public function convert($from, to)
{
    return $this->_convert($from, $to);
}
```

And then call the method convert on your object.

Answer (score 1):

Create in your model a public method that's a wrapper for the protected one.

```
public function convert($from, $to)
{
    return $this->_convert($from, $to);
}
```

Then call the `convert` method on your code:

```
Mage::getModel('my_currencyconverter/my_model')->convert('USD', 'EUR');
```